# How can I use Doctrine Annotations to change a column name in an entity subclass?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle with a new Symfony project that has to work with an existing schema. My user entity extends FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as the instructions say, but the email column is named "email_addr" instead of "email". Since the parent defines $email I can't re-declare it to attach my annotation.

```
 /**
  * @var string $emailAddr
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="email_addr", type="text", nullable=false)
  */
 protected $email;
```

The exception I get is:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                
Property "email" in "Foo\DataBundle\Entity\User" was already declared, but it must be declared only once
```

My question is either:

- How can a Doctrine2 subclass use an annotation to alter something defined in the parent?
- Or how can I override column names in the FOSUserBundle?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer:

[More about Doctrine implementations](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/doctrine.md#replacing-the-mapping-of-the-bundle)

> If you need to change the mapping (for instance to adapt the field names to a legacy database), the only solution is to write the whole mapping again without inheriting the mapping from the mapped superclass. In such case, your entity should extend directly from FOS\UserBundle\Model\User (and FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group for the group).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like doctrine 2.3 added these features. Unfortunately, SO decided that I had to duplicate information already present on their site to avoid a "trivial answer".

[@AssociationOverride and @AttributeOverride in new Doctrine 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420457/associationoverride-and-attributeoverride-in-new-doctrine-2-3)