# @AssociationOverride and @AttributeOverride in new Doctrine 2.3

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

As per title, what's the purpose of the new annotation `@AssociationOverride` and `@AttributeOverride`?

The only thing I can find on Doctrine website is:

> @AssociationOverride and @AttributeOverride (useful for Trait and
>   MappedSuperclass)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looking at the code in the [commit](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/0a09a28ec9301b371da54babb076df84a0d2033f), we can see that it is used to override a field mapping already defined in a mapped superclass / trait.

The tests included in the commit demonstrate this behaviour:

### Mapped superclass

```php
/** 
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer", name="user_id", length=150)
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(name="user_name", nullable=true, unique=false, length=250)   
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "merge", "detach"})
     * @JoinTable(name="users_groups",
     *  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * @var Address
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */ 
    protected $address;

    ...
}
```

### Subclass using `@AssociationOverride`

```php
/*  
 * @Entity
 * @AssociationOverrides({
 *      @AssociationOverride(name="groups",
 *          joinTable=@JoinTable(
 *              name="users_admingroups",
 *              joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="adminuser_id"),
 *              inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="admingroup_id")
 *          )
 *      ),
 *      @AssociationOverride(name="address",
 *          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(
 *              name="adminaddress_id", referencedColumnName="id"
 *          )
 *      )   
 * })
 */
class Admin extends User
{
    ...
}
```

### Subclass using `@AttributeOverride`

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @AttributeOverrides({
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="id",
 *          column=@Column(
 *              name     = "guest_id",
 *              type     = "integer",
 *              length   = 140
 *          )
 *      ),
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="name",
 *          column=@Column(
 *              name     = "guest_name",
 *              nullable = false,
 *              unique   = true,
 *              length   = 240
 *          )
 *      )   
 * })
 */
class Guest extends User
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That is, one is not able to change a targetEntity with a subclass of a mapped superclass? If yes, why we need these two new annotations then?

Comment: I think that's not designed to change the targetEntity, and that would not make sense anyway. Having the need to change the targetEntity would be a code smell to me, indicating the need to rethink your architecture. Instead, this allows you to change the mapping of a property to a different database field than the one from the mapped superclass (`guest_id` vs `user_id`, `adminaddress_id` vs `address_id`).