# Different between @AttributeOverride and @AssociationOverride in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What is the difference between @AttributeOverride and @AssociationOverride. Please explain me with the simple example.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420457/associationoverride-and-attributeoverride-in-new-doctrine-2-3

Answer (score 7):

From official documentation:

[@AssociationOverride](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AssociationOverride.html)

> Used to override a mapping for an entity
>   relationship

[@AttributeOverride](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html)

> Used to override the mapping of a Basic (whether explicit or default)
>   property or field or Id property or field.

Read official javadoc: is well explained with some example.

Answer (score 2):

May be that is a bit more simple:

The @AttributeOverride annotation is used to override the mapping of property or field or Id property or field.

The @AssociationOverride annotation is used to override a many-to-one or one-to-one mapping of property or field for an entity relationship.

https://javabeat.net/eclipselink-jpa-annotations-attributeoverride-associationoverride/