# Symfony2 User Entity change class variables

Tags: variables, symfony, entity

simple question but i don't know how to do it.
As an example we have User Entity for login (class below), how can i change $password to $accountPass ? Ofcourse it means that all relationships must be applied as it is $password, and all symfony2 classes must understand that variable (old) $password now is (changed to) $accountPass.

Question is about "names of variables"... Anyone know how to deal with it?

User Entity :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="_account")
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    $this->isActive = true;
}

/**
 * Get roles
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @return 
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{

}

/**
 * Get equals
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function equals(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $user->getUsername() == $this->getUsername();
}

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $salt;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean")
 */
protected $isActive;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return User
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return User
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return User
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 * @return User
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get salt
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

/**
 * Set isActive
 *
 * @param string $isActive
 * @return User
 */
public function setIsActive($isActive)
{
    $this->isActive = $isActive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get isActive
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getIsActive()
{
    return $this->isActive;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147185/927636

You have to map all fields in your Entity class and name them as you want to.

Comment: i saw this "None of the Doctrine projects currently allow overwriting part of the mapping of a mapped superclass in the child entity." and seems to be there is no correct solutions, thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $accountPass;

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->accountPass = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->accountPass;
}
```

It should be obvious of course that when you change the method name, that other classes have no way of knowing this!
All occurrences of the old method name should be changed to!

But I don't really see why you would this?

Comment: In ZendFramework you can create simple form for any columns you want for login, and you set credential fileds by your own, just wondering can i do the same in sf2

Comment: and no, it's not the way out i'm searching for :(

Comment: Ok, i think i misunderstood your question then.  
Been a long time since i used ZF, so more code (forms) on what you are trying to accomplish could make it more clear.