# Symfony UserBundle: override field name in database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

In order to share the database with another, non-Symfony based application, I want to change some field names of the User table.

The custom entity is defined like this:

```
<?php
namespace Bcg\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
...
```

I tried to override the name of the *password* field like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="encrypted_password", type="string")
 */
protected $password;
```

but that results in an error:
*MappingException: Property "password" in "Bcg\UserBundle\Entity\User" was already declared, but it must be declared only once*

What am I missing?

Comment: Duplicate question. This question has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12147185/2106834

Answer (score 0):

Have you regenerated your schema using `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` command ?

Comment: I don't want to adapt the DB to the App, but the App to the DB, thus schema update can't be the solution.

Comment: This is more a comment giving a suggestion than a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up on this and changed the other application instead.